# Add query condition for referenced user by user ID

Tags: entities, database

I have created a content type with machine name `user_points` and let's say have the following fields for this content type:

```
nid,
title,
reference_id (text),
user (reference of user entity),
points (integer)
```

the following code give me the sum of all points.

```
$storage = $this->entityTypeManager()->getStorage('node'); 
    $total_points = $storage->getAggregateQuery()
      ->condition('status', 1)
      ->aggregate('points', 'SUM')
      ->condition('type', 'user_points')
      ->execute();
```

I would like to add a condition to get total points for specific referenced user by user ID. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the machine name of user entity referenced in `user_points` content type is for example `field_my_user`, the following condition can be added to the query above to select only nodes with referenced user equal to `$user_id`

```
->condition('field_my_user.entity:user.uid', $user_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

The user id for nodes is stored in node_field_data and/or node_revision depending on some settings in your content_type. Join these tables on nid/vid and add a condition for your uid/revision_uid.

Comment: I don't look for user id of user that created the node but for user id of user that referenced in the node.